# Data not displaying correctly

Tags: php, html

I want my data to be displayed in a row.

Inside my **database** there are a lot iPhone pictures and some text associated to that particular picture.

I want that data to be shown left to right , I tried and it's working fine for picture **NOT** for text.

I would like the text to be displayed from left to right instead of top to bottom.

```
<h2 class="apple">Apple</h2>
<br>
<?php include 'config.php';
    $sql="SELECT * FROM apple";
    $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while ($fetch=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
    <a href="#"> <img src="<?php ECHO $fetch["url"];?>"width="100" height="100" alt=""></a>
    <h1> Hello</h1>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to display the data in a table with table rows and table data inside it.

```
<?php 
include ('config.php');

echo '<h2 class="apple">Apple</h2>';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM apple";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo '<table>';
    while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_all($result)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($fetch as $values) {
            echo '<td>'. $values['index of image'] . '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';

        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($fetch as $values) {
            echo '<td>'. $values['index of names'] . '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

This should get the job done.

Comment: text is showing on right side of the picture and pictures are still displaying from top to down

Comment: i want text under the picture and i want pictures from left to right

Comment: Sry i missunderstood you and updated my solution. Now you grab all the data from your database with mysqli_fetch_all so you get an associative array. Next you loop  through all pictures and put them into 1 row, then you loop throuh all names and put them into the next row. All you have to do is insert the right indexes.